# How to create a trainable linear layer for input with unknown batch size? (Keras/Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, matrix-multiplication, keras-layer

I have an input x of the following shape [?, m, n] and I would like to create a new layer of form x*w + b that retain the original shape of x.
so basically x*w should be an element-wise multiplication.

but because the batch size is unknown I'm not quite sure how to keep w as the same dimension as x.

I can't force w to be [?, m, n] and if w is [m, n] then I get error for trying multiplication between 3D and 2D

**Solved:**

```
class LinearLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LinearLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(name='w',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], input_shape[2]),
                                      initializer=RandomNormal(),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(name='b',
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], input_shape[2]),
                                      initializer=RandomNormal(),
                                      trainable=True)
        super(LinearLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        batch_size = tf.shape(x)[0]
        w_expand = tf.expand_dims(self.w, axis=0)
        w_tile = tf.tile(w_expand, multiples=[batch_size, 1, 1])
        return tf.multiply(x, w_tile) + self.b

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Comment: Do you use the same parameters for each element in your sample? Otherwise you've create a model whose parametrization depends on the input which is probably not what you want? As an aside, note that it's non-standard to denote element-wise multiplication by *xw*; this almost always denotes matrix multiplication.

Comment: @fuglede I don't want the model parametrization to depends on the number of samples. but I don't want to change the shape of the input as well. so if I start with shape [?, m, n] I want the same shape in the end just adding a trainable weights to it

Answer (score 0):

Make `w` to be [1,m,n], and then the multiplication with a [?,m,n] tensor should be straightforward.

Even better, if you can use Tensorflow operations instead of pure Keras, `x*self.W` (or more explicitly `tf.math.multiply(x,self.W)`) should work just fine (Tensorflow's broadcasting is less lame than Keras').